# How to solve a simple $2 \times n$ system

Tags: combinatorics, summation, systems-of-equations

Suppose you have the following conditions for some real numbers $a_k$ for $k=0, \dots , n$
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{k=0}^{n}ka_k=0$$
What are the values for the numbers $a_k$

**My attempt:**
Aside from the obvious $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(ka_k-a_k)=0 \Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(k-1)=0 $ which doesn't give us much,
i have tried solving for $a_1$ and $a_2$ and so on and and change the values in the second sum but again nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Just make all the numbers 0?

Comment: If $f(x)= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n$ then $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)=0$. So $f(x) = (x-1)^2p(x)$ where $p$ is arbitrary polynomial of the degree $n-2$. If $$p(x) =b_0+b_1x+...b_{n-2}x^{n-2}$$ then $$a_k = b_k-2b_{k-1}+b_{k-2}$$

Comment: You have two equations in $n$ unknowns.  If $n \gt 2$ there is not a unique solution.  You can choose $n-2$ of the $a$s as you wish and solve for the last $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n$ then $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)=0$. So $f(x) = (x-1)^2p(x)$ where $p$ is arbitrary polynomial of the degree $n-2$. If $$p(x) =b_0+b_1x+...b_{n-2}x^{n-2}$$ then for $2\leq k\leq n-2$ we have $$\boxed{a_k = b_{k}-2b_{k-1}+b_{k-2}}$$
and
$$a_n = b_{n-2}$$
$$ a_{n-1} = b_{n-3}-2b_{n-2}$$
$$ a_1 = b_1-2b_0$$
$$ a_0 =b_0$$

So for any $b_0,b_1,...b_{n-2}$  you get a solution given by upper formulas.